# NotificationListenerService автоответчик

Tags: java

Пытаюсь написать автоответчик на java. Возник вопрос: можно ли с помощью уведомления отправить сообщение в другое приложение?

Comment: Если там нет приёмника, то нет

Comment: этот вопрос можно перефразировать примерно так: я купил мобильный телефон, могу ли я теперь звонить всем людям (даже если у них мобильного телефона нет, но у меня то он есть)?

Comment: @Дмитрий Любой вопрос можно перефразировать как угодно. Я имею ввиду конкретное действие.

Я знаю что есть способ создать автоответчик (как пример приложения: autoresponder for telegram, intagram и т.д.), только меня интересует как это сделать. Пока я пришел к тому, что это делается через уведомления.

Очень надеюсь что есть знающие люди, которые скажут куда копать, а не будут перефразировать мой вопрос.